# SwiftUI + SpriteView = Gray screen

Tags: swiftui, spriteview

Xcode 13 beta 2, iOS 15 beta 2.

The following code produces a gray screen:
(The **SKScene** `GameScene.didMove(to:)` never gets called)

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

// A simple game scene with falling boxes
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let box = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        box.position = location
        box.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        addChild(box)
    }
}

// A sample SwiftUI creating a GameScene and sizing it at 300x400 points
struct ContentView: View {
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to fix / workaround this issue.
Any thoughts?

(Works on previous Xcode / Swift version)

Comment: I'm using Xcode 14.2 w/simulators on iOS 15.5 and 16.2 but still seeing this issue. Doesn't happen on actual devices. Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed in Xcode 13 beta 5 / iOS 15 beta 5.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because scene is a computed variable. So every time the view is redrawn or scene is accessed, it gets recomputed which creates and initializes a new `GameScene` object. Try something more like this, where `GameModel` and `GameScene` are only created once. (you can probably improve on it and remove having to set the size twice also):

```
class GameScene: SKScene { // keep the same }

class GameModel: ObservableObject {
  let scene: SKScene = {
    let scene = GameScene()
    scene.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 400)
    scene.scaleMode = .fill
    return scene
  }()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = GameModel()
    var body: some View {
      SpriteView(scene: model.scene)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great point on `StateObject`, but unfortunately that was not it. The same gray screen is displayed. Weirdly enough the same code works a previous Xcode / Swift version. I filled a bug to it. :-/